# How can I plot a pandas dataframe and have groupings in the x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe that is grouped by Month, and with each month is a Region with their respective Sales and Profit amounts.

I'm able to create a chart (link to the graphic is at the end of the post) but the X-axis displays the (Date, Region) for each vertical bar.  What I'm looking to display is to have each vertical bar labeled with only the respective Region, than group each of the 4 regions by the Month.

Is this possible?

Python code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 6))
result.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Pandas Dataframe contents

```
                           Profit       Sales
Order Date Region
2015-01-31 Central  -602.8452   2510.5116
           East    -1633.3880   4670.9940
           South   -1645.0817   4965.8340
           West      600.3079   6026.7360
2015-02-28 Central   330.9740   2527.5860
           East     1806.5875   6463.1330
           South     222.5703   1156.5140
           West      453.7190   1804.1780
2015-03-31 Central    51.4141   6730.2680
           East     1474.0029   6011.7410
           South    3982.8631  10322.0950
           West     4223.8177  15662.1480
2015-04-30 Central   992.0608  11642.0550
           East     1095.2726   7778.7960
           South     767.3671   5718.3335
           West     1332.7957   9056.0240
2015-05-31 Central   963.9297   8623.9030
           East     1633.5375   7481.4240
           South     429.2514   1983.7040
           West     1641.1504  12042.6555
...
```

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q1pi.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply change the ordering of the bars, you can change the order of your index and then sort the index:

```
result = result.reorder_levels(['Region', 'Order Date']).sort_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 6))
result.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

If you want 4 separate plots, you can try create 4 subplots and map a filtered dataset for each region to each of the subplot axes:

```
# reorder levels for easier index slicing
result = result.reorder_levels(['Region', 'Order Date']).sort_index()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(17, 6))
result.loc['Central'].plot.bar(ax = axes[0])
result.loc['East'].plot.bar(ax = axes[1])
result.loc['South'].plot.bar(ax = axes[2])
result.loc['West'].plot.bar(ax = axes[3])
plt.show()
```

From there you can tweak your subplot titles, axis labels, add annotation, etc. to get it to look the way you want.